# Why is my second select sql comman not working when the first one has?

Tags: php, html, sql, select

I ma trying to write a checklist usig SQL and PHP and am trying to display data from a sql database into a HTML table. Im trying to dislay it in two different tables with one displaying records that have been completed and with one displying the ones that havent. 
The code for displaying the table with records that arent complete displays them fine, but the second one does not display the records. 
Any help would be appreciated!

```
    <div class="table_undone"> 
<!--Display undone checklist items-->
    <h2>STILL TO DO</h2>
    <?php
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM checklist WHERE done = '' ORDER BY id";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            //display the header of the table
            echo "<table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>ITEM</th>
                        <th>DUE DATE</th>
                        <th>DONE</th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>";
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                //display the contents of the table
                echo "<tr>
                        <td>".$row['id']."</td>
                        <td>".$row['item']."</td>
                        <td>".$row['due_date']."</td>
                        <td>".$row['done']."</td>
                      </tr>";
            } 
            echo "</table>";
        } else {
            echo "0 RESULTS";
        }
        $conn->close();
    ?>
</div>
<div class="table_done"> 
<!--Display complete checklist items-->
    <h2>COMPLETE!</h2>
    <?php
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM checklist WHERE done != '' ORDER BY id";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            //display the header of the table
            echo "<table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>ITEM</th>
                        <th>DUE DATE</th>
                        <th>DONE</th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>";
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                //display the contents of the table
                echo "<tr>
                        <td>".$row['id']."</td>
                        <td>".$row['item']."</td>
                        <td>".$row['due_date']."</td>
                        <td>".$row['done']."</td>
                      </tr>";
            } 
            echo "</table>";
        } else {
            echo "0 RESULTS";
            echo $sql;
        }
        $conn->close();
    ?>
</div>
```

Where the second table should be it displays the statemtn 0 RESULTS SHOWN even though there are records in the database tha should be shown.

Comment: Use `<>` instead of `!=`.

Comment: How is the `done` field defined?

Comment: in mysql `!=` and `<>` are  equivalent @TheImpaler

Comment: are you sure done has empty fields? not to be confused with NULL

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If i see correctly, you closed the connection after the first one:

```
$conn->close();
```

so the second query has no connection to ride on (it uses the same $conn which was closed). Delete that line after first query (at the end).